# AutoLayout and Embedded stackview constraint conflicts

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I have a layout I'm trying to build with a vertical stackview.  Stackview is pinned at the left, top and right edges of view at 0.  I have a horizontal stackview inside which has 3 images all 30x30 that I want left aligned.  (Not spaced out across horizontal stack.)

XCode continues to give me conflicting constraints errors here.  I believe its because it wants my stackview to be at 100% of outer vertical stack view width.  I can add in a random view that stretches and it fixes the problem, but this seems VERY clunky.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Did you set the Alignment property of the Vertical StackView to `Leading`?

Comment: @DonMag - Good idea!  I just set it to leading for vertical stack view.  Unfortunately it did not resolve my auto-layout errors.

Comment: @DonMag - Correction, I may have made a mistake...  I think you have solved this for me!  Crossing my fingers here...

Comment: Can you post a screen shot? As far as I can tell, this is what you were after, and I get no auto layout warnings or errors (I used labels instead of image views, but that would have no effect)... https://imgur.com/a/DBCO4

Comment: God Bless you @DonMag

Answer (score 3):

So, @DonMag has answered my question  - The vertical stack view should be leading which will not force every horizontal stack view inside to expand to its width.  Thanks @DonMag!